# Admin view access to other normal users in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How can I give access for the admin views to normal users in django?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the admin site and edit the user. Check the check box (under permissions) where it says:

"Staff status

Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."

You then need to grant them appropriate permissions for them to actually see things in the admin site. That is done just below this checkbox. If you want them to be able to do everything, check the "superuser" checkbox.

Is this what you mean?

#### Update

The OP actually wants to apply these permissions to a group of users. To do this, go to the admin site > Auth > Groups. Create a new group. Give it the permissions you want the group of users to have. You then need to go to each user and add them to this group. They will also need to be given "staff status" in order to log in to the admin site.

Is that what you are after?

Comment: no it was not what I meant. Actually not an individual user level, but a whole group